# Are muslims allowed to smoke weed?

Tags: practical-islam, islamic-philosophy

During the lockdown, I have been walking on parks in London. I have noticed that some muslims gather in the afternoon/evening on these parks and smoke weed. I, as a non muslim, was rather surprised as some women in the group wear hijabs, and the guys some traditional clothing. However, they are clearly high and the smell of weed is clear and strong. I have nothing against smoking weed, but I was wondering if this is a practice allowed in Islam (even though weed is illegal in the UK).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no smoking weed is not allowed in Islam

all intoxicating are forbidden in Islam

the prophet Mohammed say that (every intoxicating is vintage and all vintage is forrbidden)

Answer (score 0):

Smoking weed is not allowed in Islam and I think its not allowed in all the other religions also.

And all the other intoxicating things also forbidden in ISLAM.